# Using the Macro SEC_IS_BEING_DEBUGGED_RETURN_NIL in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gdb, cycript

I learnt about the below piece of code, which is claimed to prevent [Method Swizzling](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-8-method-swizzling-using-cycript/) to some extent.

```
#ifndef DEBUG
SEC_IS_BEING_DEBUGGED_RETURN_NIL();
#endif
```

But while including in my project for testing, I get an error.

> Implicit declaration of function 'SEC_IS_BEING_DEBUGGED_RETURN_NIL' is
>   invalid in C99

Can someone help me out on this error, if I need to include any library header for the same.

Comment: `SEC_IS_BEING_DEBUGGED_RETURN_NIL` is not a defined macro in the context that you have tried to use it. You need to define it or import a file that does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't intend to answer my own question. From the comment above, I did a search for any such implementation. And Found this [In a GitHub Project](https://github.com/x128/MemeCollector/blob/master/Meme%20Collector/NSObject%2BdebugCheck.h). Which is a category of `NSObject`

Perhaps, it would help anyone in `future`.

```
#define SEC_IS_BEING_DEBUGGED_RETURN_NIL()  size_t size = sizeof(struct kinfo_proc); \
                                            struct kinfo_proc info; \
                                            int ret, name[4]; \
                                            memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct kinfo_proc)); \
                                            name[0] = CTL_KERN; \
                                            name[1] = KERN_PROC; \
                                            name[2] = KERN_PROC_PID; \
                                            name[3] = getpid(); \
                                            if ((ret = (sysctl(name, 4, &info, &size, NULL, 0)))) { \
                                            if (ret) return nil; \
                                            } \
                                            if (info.kp_proc.p_flag & P_TRACED) return nil
```

Credits to maker of this

> //   Created by Derek Selander on a happy day. //
>   //  Copyright (c)
>   //  2013 Derek Selander. All rights reserved. //