# How detect when the app is debugged with gdb (iOS)

Tags: ios, gdb

Is there any way detect when the app is debugged with gdb in iOS

So my question is next , is there any way how I can get current debugger which is using application and attached process
only checking if process is attached does not solve my problem

Thank You

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [Detect if Cycript/Substrate or gdb is attached to an iOS app's process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131835/detect-if-cycript-substrate-or-gdb-is-attached-to-an-ios-apps-process); [Detecting if iOS app is run in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4744826/253056).

Comment: Thanks for your response but my question is a little difference ,
Only checking if process is attached does not solve my problem , I want get current debugger which is using application and attached process

Comment: You should probably edit your question to make it clear what you want to achieve, exactly,